# How to make jquery grid column as read-only?

Tags: jquery

I need to make one column as read-only in jquery grid.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('selector').attr('readonly', true);
});
```

Comment: not only the column I need to make entire row values to readonly.. he can not edit there anything?